# Extract fields from log file where data is stored half json and half plain text

Tags: json, pyspark

I am new to Spark, and want to read a log file and create a dataframe out of it. My data is half json, and I cannot convert it into a dataframe properly. Here below is first row in the file;

```
[2017-01-06 07:00:01] userid:444444 11.11.111.0 info {"artist":"Tears For Fears","album":"Songs From The Big Chair","song":"Everybody Wants To Rule The World","id":"S4555","service":"pandora"}
```

See first part is plain text and the last part between { } is json, I tried few things, converting it first to RDD then map and split then convert back to DataFrame, but I cannot extract the values from Json part of the row, is there a trick to extract fields in this context?

Final output will be like;

```
TimeStamp             userid   ip             artist           album                      song                                   id          service
2017-01-06 07:00:01   444444   11.11.111.0    Tears For Fears  Songs From The Big Chair   Everybody Wants To Rule The World    S4555         pandora
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to parse out the pieces with a Python UDF into a tuple then tell spark to convert the RDD to a dataframe.  The easiest way to do this is probably a regular expression.  For example:

```
import re
import json

def parse(row):
    pattern = ' '.join([
        r'\[(?P<ts>\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\]',
        r'userid:(?P<userid>\d+)',
        r'(?P<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)',
        r'(?P<level>\w+)',
        r'(?P<json>.+$)'
    ])
    match = re.match(pattern, row)
    parsed_json = json.loads(match.group('json'))
    return (match.group('ts'), match.group('userid'), match.group('ip'), match.group('level'), parsed_json['artist'], parsed_json['song'], parsed_json['service'])


lines = [
'[2017-01-06 07:00:01] userid:444444 11.11.111.0 info {"artist":"Tears For Fears","album":"Songs From The Big Chair","song":"Everybody Wants To Rule The World","id":"S4555","service":"pandora"}'
]


rdd = sc.parallelize(lines)
df = rdd.map(parse).toDF(['ts', 'userid', 'ip', 'level', 'artist', 'song', 'service'])

df.show()
```

This prints

```
+-------------------+------+-----------+-----+---------------+--------------------+-------+
|                 ts|userid|         ip|level|         artist|                song|service|
+-------------------+------+-----------+-----+---------------+--------------------+-------+
|2017-01-06 07:00:01|444444|11.11.111.0| info|Tears For Fears|Everybody Wants T...|pandora|
+-------------------+------+-----------+-----+---------------+--------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this was very valuable, just wanted to use pyspark and it worked for me as seen in my own answer below. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following, just some parsing utilizing pyspark power;

```
parts=r1.map( lambda x: x.value.replace('[','').replace('] ','###')
     .replace(' userid:','###').replace('null','"null"').replace('""','"NA"')
     .replace(' music_info {"artist":"','###').replace('","album":"','###')
     .replace('","song":"','###').replace('","id":"','###')
     .replace('","service":"','###').replace('"}','###').split('###'))
people = parts.map(lambda p: (p[0], p[1],p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6], p[7]))

schemaString = "timestamp mac userid_ip artist album song id service"
fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in schemaString.split()]
```

With this I got almost what I want, and performance was super fast.

```
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------    +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|          timestamp|              mac|           userid_ip|              artist|               album|                song|                  id|service|
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|2017-01-01 00:00:00|00:00:00:00:00:00|111122  22.235.17...|The United States...|  This Is Christmas!|Do You Hear What ...|            S1112536|pandora|
|2017-01-01 00:00:00|00:11:11:11:11:11|123123 108.252.2...|                  NA|  Dinner Party Radio|                  NA|                null|pandora|
```

Comment: This approach is a little risky.  If for example your song titles end up including a '[' you will end up replacing it with your column separator.  Also if your JSON keys end up in a different order your replace will fail.